# Trying to send QueryParams through .CSV in postman for multiple GET Requests

Tags: csv, automation, postman, rest

[image]

I'm trying to pass query params for two different GET endpoints through CSV and both GET endpoints are trying to read the first "policyQueryParams". I except my second GET to take the data from "submissionQueryParams"

Comment: Please show how did you set things up on postman.

Comment: Just to double-check, are you using Collection Runner to iterate over your .csv? Did you save recent changes before running the Collection Runner?